# CS8613 warning in async version of method

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, nullable-reference-types

I have Net6.0 project with nullable reference types enabled.

In this project, I have sync and async method for finding an entity by ID:

```
    public virtual TEntity GetByIdOrThrow(TId id)
    {
        return QueryEntities()
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id)) ?? throw NotFoundException;
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIdOrThrowAsync(TId id)
    {
        var entity = await QueryEntities()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
        return entity ?? throw NotFoundException;
    }
```

I am getting compiler warning in the async method:

```
Nullability of reference types in return type of 'Task<TEntity> RepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext, TId>.GetByIdOrThrowAsync(TId id)' doesn't match implicitly implemented member 'Task<TEntity?> IRepositoryBase<TEntity, TId>.GetByIdOrThrowAsync(TId id)'
```

Just for sure, `NotFoundException` is my property (intelliSense tells `NotFoundException is not null here.`)

Why do I have problems in the async version? Null entity can't be returned as I am throwing exception in case of null entity before returning the entity.

Comment: Can you please add a full repro? I'm assuming this is an implementation of some interface? Can you please add it?

Comment: @GuruStron OMG, I forgot to update interface.. thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on error it seems that you have an interface `IRepositoryBase<TEntity, TId>` which has a method declared with nullable type `Task<TEntity?> GetByIdOrThrowAsync(TId id)`. You need to match this definition in the implementation:

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity?> GetByIdOrThrowAsync(TId id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or based on the implementation (and the second, non-async version) it seems that it should not be nullable in the first place in the interface, so fix it there to be `Task<TEntity> GetByIdOrThrowAsync(TId id)` there.

Comment: Yes I forgot to update interface.. thank you.

Comment: @Majak NP, was glad to help!